# Is the domain of a sublinear functional $f: X \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ a vector subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a vector space. A map $p:X \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ is called *sublinear* if $p(0) = 0, p(tx)=tp(x)$, and $p(x+y) \le p(x)+p(y)$ for all $t>0$ and $x,y \in X$. The domain of $p$ is defined as $\operatorname{dom} p := \{x\in X \mid p(x) <+\infty\}$.

**Theorem:** Let $p:X \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ be sublinear. Then $\operatorname{dom} p$ is convex.

*Proof:* Fix $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ and $x, y\in \operatorname{dom} p$. Indeed,
$$
p(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \le p(\lambda x) + p((1-\lambda)y) = \lambda p(x) + (1-\lambda) p(y) <+\infty.
$$
It follows that $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in \operatorname{dom} p$. This completes the proof.

> Is $\operatorname{dom} p$ a vector subspace of $X$? If not, please provide a counter-example.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you so much! Could you post your example as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done, thanks. ${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x) = x$ for $x \ge 0$ and $+\infty$ otherwise on the real line.